# Can I use the VHS Logo for a commercial Artwork?

Tags: copyright, trademark

I'm planning to make an artwork as a spotify sonng cover with a VHS style and I was wondering if I could have used this logo for this job:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/VHS_logo.svg/1200px-VHS_logo.svg.png

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no.

The VHS logo seems to be registered as a trademark under JVC - a japanese company later purchased by Panasonic.

Not sure how the review process works on Spotify, but they will likely not publish artwork which would include recognizable logos.